# 'Go To Definition' opens tab on right and doesn't keep open (implied), how to open as normal?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community.

If I right click, say, a class name in some code and 'Go To Definition' it'll open the file's tab on the right instead of left (as it would if I double clicked the same file to open it).

On the tab is a button saying 'Keep Tab Open', implying it might be closed at any point automatically; though it never was.

How can I make 'Go To Definition' on a class just open the file as normal, on the left, like double clicking a file?

I've searched extensively and can't even find any references to what's going on.

[image]

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That feature is called a Preview Tab.  Only one Preview Tab can be open at a time, so the next action you take that would open a different one would close this one (hence the "Keep tab open" button).

You can find the settings for it in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows.

[image: Preview Tab options]

Comment: Thanks. The whac-a-mole we have to play disabling the new useless features Microsoft puts in Visual Studio with every new version should be an Olympic sport...

Comment: It's difficult when a new feature is added to decide if it should be the default or not. I like the tab being on the right when it's code that's not in my project.

Comment: Paul: I like your idea to open on the right if it's not in the project. Unfortunately it does it for every file. Thank FSM I can turn it off.

For code outside my project, I'd love it to open my 2nd monitor. At this point I'm sure most VS users are running more than 1 monitor.